# When trying to output scrambled word from another method I get System.Char[]

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I send a word to my scramble method that returns the scrambled word but when I try to output the word I get System.Char[]. I have seen another thread that is similar to mine but he used .ToCharArray and .ToString and that was his problem and I couldn't figure out mine from that. This is C# and I am still learning. I do not want answers. I want to know what am I doing wrong and suggestions on how to fix it. Thank you in advance.(I don't know why the for loop is showing up that way)

```
namespace Farmer_JumbleApp
{

//Author: Aaron Farmer
class Jumble
{
    string hiddenWord = "";//chosen word from array
    string[] words = new string[] { "sauce", "iphone", "tick", "time", "think", "dream", "awake" };
    Random randy = new Random();

    string display = " ";

    public Jumble()
    { }

    public void Master()
    {

    UIJumble Graphics = new UIJumble();
    Admin Info = new Admin();

        string userGuess = " ";        
        int randNum = 0;
        int quit;
        bool cont = true;//Loop condition
        char[] scrambledWord = new char[] { };//Scrambled word


        randNum = randy.Next(words.Length);
        hiddenWord = words[randNum];
        scrambledWord = Scramble(hiddenWord);

        while (cont)
        {
            display = "The Scrambled Word is: ";
            Graphics.DisplayOnLine(display);

            for (int i = 0; i < scrambledWord.Length; i++)
            {
                display = "" + scrambledWord;
                Graphics.DisplayOnLine(display);
            }

            //display = "  ";
            //Graphics.DisplayString(display);

            display = "\n\n\nEnter your guess: ";
            Graphics.DisplayOnLine(display);

            userGuess = Graphics.RecieveString();

            if (userGuess == hiddenWord)
            {
                Graphics.CleanUp();
                Info.MyInfo();
                display = "You are correct";
                Graphics.DisplayString(display);

            }//end of if


            else if (userGuess != hiddenWord)
            {
                display = "Sorry, You are Incorrect";
                Graphics.DisplayString(display);
            }//end of else if


            display = "Would you like to quit?\n1. Yes\n2. No";
            Graphics.DisplayString(display);
            quit = Graphics.RecieveInt();

            if (quit == 1)
            {
                cont = false;   
            }



        }//End of While_Loop
        display = "Hope you enjoyed";
        Graphics.DisplayString(display);
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }//End of Master Method
```

-----------------------------Next Method--------------------

```
    public char[] Scramble(string word)
    {

        int randNum = 0;
        int random;
        char temp;



        randNum = randy.Next(words.Length);
        hiddenWord = words[randNum];

        var displayWord = new char[word.Length]; //initializing array
        for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
            {
                do
                    random = randy.Next(word.Length);
                while (displayWord[random] != 0);
                temp = word[i];
                displayWord[random] = temp;
            }


        return displayWord;
    }//End of Scramble Method


}//End of Class
}//End of Namespace
```

Comment: you should make scramble return a string. `return new string(displayword)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < scrambledWord.Length; i++)
{
    display = "" + scrambledWord;
    Graphics.DisplayOnLine(display);
}
```

should be replaced with

```
for (int i = 0; i < scrambledWord.Length; i++)
{
    display = "" + scrambledWord[i];
    Graphics.DisplayOnLine(display);
}
```

as `"" + scrambledWord` will use `scrambledWord.ToString()` which returns `System.Char[]` (its type name)

**OR**

shortly put, as `Joel Coehoorn` has suggested:

```
Graphics.DisplayOnLine(new String(scrambledWord));
```

Comment: Or, better: `display = new String(scrambledWord);`